# Where is the NiViewer in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation, environment-variables, shared-library, kinect

I am pretty much new to Ubuntu file and directory system. I installed OpenNi2 using `sudo apt install libopenni2-dev` but now could not find the NiViewer executable to test the installation. I looked in `/usr/bin` and `usr/local/bin` but its not there.However when I download OpenNI2 from [here](https://structure.io/openni) it contains a NiViewer which does not run. But when i execute the `install.sh` then the NiViewer runs. I looked into the `install.sh` file. It has this two parts I guess...installing the udev rules and exporting the environmental variables. This is how the `install.sh` file looks

```sh
if [ `whoami` != root ]; then
echo Please run this script with sudo
exit
fi

ORIG_PATH=`pwd`
cd `dirname $0`
SCRIPT_PATH=`pwd`
cd $ORIG_PATH

if [ "`uname -s`" != "Darwin" ]; then
  # Install UDEV rules for USB device
  cp ${SCRIPT_PATH}/primesense-usb.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/557-primesense-usb.rules 
fi

OUT_FILE="$SCRIPT_PATH/OpenNIDevEnvironment"

echo "export OPENNI2_INCLUDE=$SCRIPT_PATH/Include" > $OUT_FILE
echo "export OPENNI2_REDIST=$SCRIPT_PATH/Redist" >> $OUT_FILE
chmod a+r $OUT_FILE
```

My questions are the following:

1. can I make NiViewer run without running the install.sh file by just the things available after I have `sudo apt install libopenni2-dev`? i.e. can the udev rules be set without running the install.sh file?(environmental variables already has the path `/usr/lib` added to it I guess)
2. If I install OpenNI2 using the install.sh file then the location of the libs gets altered. Its not the usual `/usr/lib`. How will any cmake detect the location of OpenNI libs if I need OpenNI to build any other library like PCL or OpenCV?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you actually installed OpenNI.  To install download either the [32bit](https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.occipital.openni/OpenNI-Linux-x86-2.2.0.33.tar.bz2) or [64bit](https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.occipital.openni/OpenNI-Linux-x64-2.2.0.33.tar.bz2).  Once downloaded go to the download location, normally the Downloads folder, and extract the downloaded file.  Once extracted just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to where the file was extracted, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

Once down run:

```
cd Tools
./NiViewer
```

to run the viewer.